# Give space between line and label value in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created achartengine line chart for my application. All works perfect but Y axis label and line both mixed up.

And also result value display on above the line.

You can check in below image. Label is on line.

[image]

I have tried for Y axis.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
```

And for result value.

```
SimpleSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(3);
incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(35.0f);
incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download latest jar file for [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/download.html). Because this properly is available after version 1.1.0.

After use

```
multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
```

This work perfect for me.
hope this help you.